# Max number of file packaged with an app

Tags: android, ios

Bit of an odd question but..

I am currently building an app, it will essentailly be a hotel listings directory with a few frills.

Having never made an app like this before I have suddenly found my self with the following question but cannot find the answer...

Is the there a limit the number of file you can package the app with, ie submit to itunes...

The reason I ask is potentially I will want to submit my app with a minimum 700+ images each in their own directory resulting in 1400+ files (assuming a directory is a file). I can get the size of the images to fit the 'over the air' max app download size.. but cannot find if there is a limit ot the number of files you can submit...

Comment: You don't submit android apps to itunes.

Comment: Really? but I thought Google was owned by Crapple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no as such limit for the number of files to be uploaded. However, as you mentioned it would be better to download your files from the app after installation.
This would help you reduce the binary size.
This is for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Your app usually comes in *one* .apk file. Your resources included. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29 So its size is what matters.

You may want to double check the architecture of your app, it sounds like you want a webservice.